# How to block all outbound traffic to 10.0.0.0/8 subnet except to 10.20.20.0/24 subnet using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables

I have a peculiar situation.

I need to block all outbound connections to 10.0.0.0/8 subnet but allow connections to 10.20.20.0/24 subnet.

How can I do this using iptables on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iptables executes rules from top to bottom, so first you add the rule to allow outbound connections to 10.20.20.0/24, and then you add the rule to deny the outbound connections to 10.0.0.0/8.

I think something like this will work:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.20.20.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```